# Fluent NHibernate third party table mapping using code first

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, code-first

I am using NHibernate code first approach in my application. My application interacts with the third party applications and the user has the privilege to connect to their database and run query against any of their table through UI. Now the situation is I can map all the tables of my database but I am not sure how to map the tables of third party databases. User can connect to more than one third party database and can view any number of tables and query against them as per the permission applied. It means we don't have any fixed number of tables. Any idea how to map these tables?

Answer (score 0):

Without defining mappings for the said third party tables I can't see how Hibernate can know how to interrogate them. I don't know of any auto configuration in Hibernate that can take a schema in the database, and support querying them.

I've only used the NHibernate port with fluent NHibernate in which you can define readonly mappings, but the mappings in NHibernate still need to exist otherwise you can't use a session  to query a specific type.

Sorry I can't be of more help.